# is there any way to know the best port to use

Tags: java, netbeans, server, client, rmi

I tried different ports and i get  the same message
`java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1234; nested exception is:` 
         `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind`

Comment: check ports and maybe close some application? https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/10/how-to-check-which-application-is-using-which-port/

Comment: Use port 1099. It has been reserved for RMI for over 25 years.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the 1099 port after use taskkill command
thanks, @user207421